# AVD is not available in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**builder-3.0.1.pom.** exists in the destination folder rather than  **builder-3.0.1.jar**

```
  Error:Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.1). Searched in the following locations: 
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar
```

Comment: go to sdk and check if avd is installed or not.in case it isn't install it

Comment: I check sdk. AVD is installed.

Comment: can you add **build.gradle** where your **com.android.tools.build** version is set

Comment: then you need to install the missing packages.when you open android studio it gives some error and recommend to install some packages

Comment: I choose every thing in sdk and install all of them. but the problem is same builder-3.0.1.jar missing.

Comment: //S...O...S //.

Comment: where I can download builder-3.0.1.jar?

Comment: I delete all folders A.S and reinstall it. Now the problem is solved.